# Wildcard for apt proxy settings

Tags: apt, updates, proxy

I work on a number of Ubuntu 16.04 servers that downloads packages from a mix of internal mirror of Ubuntu repos, and external repos (security, backports). 
There is no direct connection to the external repos. All internet connections go through a proxy server.

Due to the mix of internal/external repos, I need to set up proxy settings per domain:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy::security.ubuntu.com "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
Acquire::http::Proxy::us.archive.ubuntu.com "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
```

is there a way to use wildcard to specify ubuntu.com domains? For example

```
Acquire::http::Proxy::*.ubuntu.com "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
```

I have tried a couple of syntax but have not gotten it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `privoxy` as a... well, another proxy! between apt and your actual proxy.

Then in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` you can pass all traffic to `privoxy`:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://localhost:8118";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://localhost:8118";
```

And then in `privoxy` config `/etc/privoxy/config` decide how to manage and forward the traffics.

Like:

```
forward   192.168.1.*                .
forward   us.archive.ubuntu.com      .
forward    *.ubuntu.com              http://127.0.0.1:8080
forward   security.ubuntu.com        http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

In this example `us` and `192.168.1.*` will go directly, `*.ubuntu` and `security` will go through your proxy.

Comment: Sorry if my question aren't very clear. Forwarding everything to a proxy will not cut it because I use a combination of internal and external repos.

Comment: If I'm getting it right you can also config local networks in `privoxy`, see updated config.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the following helps you by setting default proxies and the rest is figured out by itself.

https://github.com/hastmu/apt-proxy-detect

As it uses the working proxy for the given url and direct connect if none of them is working.

Enjoy.